# Защищенный конструктор в c++

Tags: c++

Понимаю, что это все делать скорей всего бессмысленно, но мне интересна причина результата.

Почему этот код:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:

        A()
        {
        }

};

class B : public A
{
public:
        void f()
        {
                A a;
        }       
};

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
test.cpp:18:5: error: ‘A::A()’ is protected within this context
   18 |   A a;
      |     ^
test.cpp:7:2: note: declared protected here
    7 |  A()
      |  ^
```

Ведь класс B может использовать Protected члены класса A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что `A a;` - другой объект. Доступ к полям родительского класса осуществляется только в пределах одного объекта. Т.е. в данном случае контекст другой.

Попробуйте код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() { b = 5;}
protected:
    int b;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f() {
        std::cout << this->b << std::endl;
        A a;
        std::cout << a.b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка компиляции:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void B::f()’:
main.cpp:14:18: error: ‘int A::b’ is protected within this context
   std::cout << a.b << std::endl;
                  ^
main.cpp:7:6: note: declared protected here
  int b;
```

При этом `this->b` принимается.

Comment: Да действительно, спасибо. Еще заметил странное поведение компилятора: https://ideone.com/6ZwWwD здесь ошибку он не выдаст, но если в main создать объект типа B, то тогда она появится. По моему странно, что в первом случае компилятор не выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Потому-что вы могли бы создать конструкторы другие с другими аргументами и с хорошими правами. Конструктор по умолчанию просто у вас запрещён. `=delete` @VanechikSpace